# SQL: How to make multiple row data into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to make my data from :-

```
Customer Product TransactionType Quantity Value
  A       ItemA        Sale         1      10
  A       ItemA        Refund       1      10
  C       ItemB        Sale         1       5
```

To following structure:-

```
Customer Product SaleValue SaleQuantity RefundValue RefundQuantity 
   A      ItemA        10          1           10           1
   C      ItemB         5          1            0           0
```

I just want to make TransactionType & Quantity in order to split into individual txn type column & its own quantity. I tried to use MSSQL Pivot function, but it does not suit my need.
I don't expect full answer, but at least I need some ideas on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` _expressions_ to do _conditional aggregation_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
select customer, product, 
       sum(case when transactiontype = 'sale' then value else 0 end) as salevalue,
       sum(case when transactiontype = 'sale' then Quantity else 0 end) as saleqty,
       sum(case when transactiontype = 'Refund' then value else 0 end) as Refundvalue,
       sum(case when transactiontype = 'Refund' then Quantity else 0 end) as Refundqty
from table t
group by customer, product
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pivoting logic:

```
SELECT
    Customer,
    Product,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'Sale'   THEN Value END) AS SaleValue,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'Sale'   THEN Quantity END) AS SaleQuantity,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'Refund' THEN Value END) AS RefundValue,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TransactionType = 'Refund' THEN Quantity END) AS RefundQuantity
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Customer,
    Product;
```